# HDFS storage check shows different values

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I faced a weird situation where i'm getting different results from `hdfs dfs -du` command and what i see in `cloudera` manager `UI`, i read about the differences between the 2 but didn't any clue that could help me to catch the issue and solved it.

I also deleted all the snapshots and disallowed them, but the storage didn't change.

Below is the output :

```
[cloudera-scm@roor-chc101 root]$ hdfs dfs -du -h -s .
2.3 G  5.8 G  .
[cloudera-scm@roor-chc101 root]$ hdfs dfs -du -h -s /
250.3 T  749.3 T
```

Cloudera manager UI

I also checked the `hdfs dfsadmin -report` which shows the same results as the UI

```
Configured Capacity:    1.54 PB
DFS Used:   897.77 TB
Non DFS Used:   2.98 GB
DFS Remaining:  682.27 TB
DFS Used%:  56.82%
DFS Remaining%: 43.18%
Block Pool Used:    897.77 TB
Block Pool Used%:   56.82%
DataNodes usages% (Min/Median/Max/stdDev):  11.17% / 58.94% / 69.35% / 13.31%
Live Nodes  45 (Decommissioned: 0)
Dead Nodes  0 (Decommissioned: 0)
Decommissioning Nodes   0
Total Datanode Volume Failures  0 (0 B)
Number of Under-Replicated Blocks   0
Number of Blocks Pending Deletion   0
Block Deletion Start Time   8/14/2017, 10:57:30 AM
```

Comment: First of all, the commands `hdfs dfs -du -h -s .` and `hdfs dfs -du -h -s /` are different. Also, I think you missed to provide output from Cloudera UI.

Answer (score 0):

i added hdfs dfs -du -h -s . and hdfs dfs -du -h -s / just to show nothing that i may missed which could be under /user/cloudera-scm.

The cloudera manager UI shows the same value as the hdfs dfsadmin -report.

BTW, i solved the issue where i find /tmp/logs/cloudera-scm used 150T and still intersting why this volume wasn't taken into consideration when i ran hdfs dfs -du -h -s